# How can I create a polygon from points and assign it a color in QGIS using python?

Tags: qgis, python

I want to create a new vector layer, containing a polygon from a set of given points, and giving it a color.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out from other questions

```
# create a memory layer with points
layer1 =  QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points' , "memory")
pr = layer1.dataProvider() 

# add the first point
pt = QgsFeature()
point1 = QgsPoint(50,50)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()

# add the second point
pt = QgsFeature()
point2 = QgsPoint(100,150)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point2))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent
layer1.updateExtents()

# add the third point
pt = QgsFeature()
point3 = QgsPoint(200,150)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point3))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent
layer1.updateExtents()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer1])


# add polygon layer
layer2 =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'poly' , "memory",0)
pr = layer2.dataProvider() 
poly = QgsFeature()
points = [point1,point2,point3]
poly.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
pr.addFeatures([poly])
layer2.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer2])
mapinstance = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
mapinstance.removeMapLayer(layer1.id())


props = { 'color' : '255, 128, 0', 'style' : 'no', 'style' : 'solid' }
s = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple(props)
layer2.setRendererV2( QgsSingleSymbolRendererV2( s ) )
layer2.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer2)
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```